# Drop the max item and the min item in a window when using pandas rolling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I want to do is like this:

1. Get a rolling window on a data series by `rolling(5,center=True)`
2. Drop the max and the min item in the window.
3. Calculate the mean value of the remained 3 pieces of data.

How to do this by `pandas.DataFrame.rolling().apply()` or `pandas.DataSeries.rolling().apply()`?

Comment: can you provide us with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the trick for you?

```
df.rolling(5,center = True,axis =0).apply(lambda x: sum(sorted(x)[1:4])
```